# visual studio pre/post build events skipping files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I have configured pre build events for a proj in visual studio.
All the files are copied in a particular folder as a part of this build command.

Recently i have added crx and xpi files in source folder.
These files alone are not getting copied to the destination folder.

Here is the build command:copy "$(SolutionDir)DLLRequired*.*" "$(TargetDir)"

here even though i have used "*.*", it skips the crx and xpi files.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If these files are part of your project - you need to right click on them, select **properties** and in `Copy to Output Directory` select `Copy always`.

If these files are dynamic or are not part of your project - you should try doing this: `XCOPY $(ProjectDir)\Libs\DLLRequired*.* $(TargetDir) /Y /R` - this is using `ProjectDir` instead of `SolutionDir` and should always work.

Also if something does not work - check out `Output windows` for any error messages.